# AngularFire - Firebase Auth showing error

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angularfire2, angularfire

In VS Code when I use `firebase.auth` I get this error:

> Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'typeof
> import("/Users/USER-NAME/angular/PROJECT-NAME/node_modules/firebase/index")'.ts(2339)

This is how I imported firebase:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/';
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to use: `firebase.default.auth`

Guess there was an update, but the AngularFire Auth [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) does not reflect those changes just yet.

I wish there was a better way to communicate some of these code-breaking updates...

Anyways, hopes this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

also use following instead of 'firebase.auth'

> firebase.default.auth